# How to simplify the following series for $m=n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can anyone simplify the following series for $m=n$
[image: double infinite series]

Comment: $m=n$ or $m=n!$ ?

Comment: it is m=n not m=n! i made a typo mistake

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\sum_{m\ge 1}\tanh^{2m-1}u=\frac{\tanh u}{1-\tanh u}=\frac{e^{2u}-1}{2}$$ Hence the given sum is $$S=\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^2}\frac{e^{nx}-1}{2}=-\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{\alpha^{n}}{2n^2}-\frac{\zeta(2)}{4}$$ where $\alpha=-e^{x}$. It remains to evaluate the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{\alpha^{n-1}}{n^2}$.

Comment: thanks for your solution. I am also interested in finding a closed form solution of proposed double infinite series if it is possible.

Comment: I just gave you the solution of that double infinite sum, only not in closed form but in the form of another series $\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{\alpha^{n-1}}{n^2}$ which is not so straightforward to evaluate I guess, but it may not be too hard. I will try to have a go on that later.

Comment: thanks for your kind support